# Post compilation hook in Compass

Tags: hook, sass, compass-sass

I need a Compass hook after compiler compile all SCSS files to CSS in STANDALONE (no Rails) project.

Is there any post-compile hook in compass other than editing "compiler.rb" (which is not good solution, because of gem updates)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I found it ;)
Compass has this hooks:

- on_sprite_saved
- on_sprite_generated
- on_sprite_removed
- on_stylesheet_saved (this is what I was looked for)
- on_stylesheet_error

Sad, that on http://compass-style.org/ there is no info about any hook.

Comment: Now I see. Hard to find such things on compass site. I think they need to rebuild theirs docs ;)

Comment: Brilliant! Now I can cal `drush cc css-js` when my css is updated to clear Drupal's stylesheet cache.

Answer (score 1):

The Compass callbacks are documented in the **Callbacks** section of http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/#callbacks.

The `on_stylesheet_saved` hook will fire after a .css file is compiled. You can invoke it by adding the following to the bottom of your config.rb file:

```
on_stylesheet_saved do |file|
  #Do Ruby stuff. Below outputs to command line.
  puts ">>>> ZOMG"
end
```